# What is the value of REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am Xamarin developer and I studied this:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi

I want to call the method "startResolutionForResult" but to do that I need to know the value of REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS. In the Xamarin GPS Api, the second argument of this method is just an integer.

It may sound like a stupid question but the value is not documented and there is only one page in the android documentation that refers to it:
https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:developers.google.com+REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS&filter=0

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Holy crap, after much searching I found the official Google sample, which defines this constant to `0x1`.

```
protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;
```

The Sample and the constant in question [can be found on GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java#L61).

(old github link is broken. [Check the new one](https://github.com/android/location-samples/blob/1e9d5122894ad0ed100fc6e8f72a5f21c790cd86/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java#L61))

It seems this value is just an int just like when you use `StartActivityForResult()` to make sure we are returning from something we requested.

Comment: It's 'just an int' _except_ that if you happen to choose a negative value the Android system dialog will not be shown when calling `startActivityForResult()` and all you'll get is a cryptic message in your system log talking about how the caller could not be found and asking if you passed a negative value.  So technically speaking, it's a _positive_ integer if you want it to actually work.

Comment: The link is broken. Updated link: https://github.com/android/location-samples/blob/1e9d5122894ad0ed100fc6e8f72a5f21c790cd86/LocationSettings/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationsettings/MainActivity.java

Comment: @MahenGandhi thanks. I just suggest the new update

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS has no particular value and is not a constant. It is the request code which is used for referencing it in callback function `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`

Since this function is called on other occasions too, the request code is used to identify which task called it and do the needed. Put an unique integer there to distinguish it uniquely in the range (0- max(int)). -1 hides the dialog box and any value below -1 simply crashes the app.
It is pretty similar to `requestPermissions()` where the extra 'int' is used for referencing in callback function `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

Thanks,
Indra