# what is REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING?

Tags: android, gps, location

I'm following this doc:  https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html
REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING isn't defined but used, and I can't find its value after doing several searchs, all I found is that : [What is the value of REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572323/what-is-the-value-of-request-check-settings)
someone giving it a "random" value (provided link not working), can someone please tell me how to get the value? or am I supposed to define it myself?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING isn't defined but used

The "training" at the Android developer site routinely skips stuff.

> can someone please tell me how to get the value? or am I supposed to define it myself?

You are supposed to define it yourself. `startResolutionForResult()` works like `startActivityForResult()`, `requestPermissions()`, and similar methods:

- You supply an `int` to the call
- You get that `int` in the callback (e.g., `onActivityResult()` for `startActivityForResult()`), to help you identify what call triggered the callback

In [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.6/Location/FusedNew), I used a value of 61124 (defined there as `REQUEST_RESOLUTION`) in my `startResolutionForResult()` call.